# Programmatically create columns in a View

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

This should be easy.  I want to populate a grid with a custom data source at runtime.  For some reason, it simply does not work.

Running via a unit test

```
[TestMethod]
public void Runtest() {
    TestForm form = new TestForm();
    TestControl control = new TestControl();
    form.Controls.Add(control);
    control.LoadData();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

The relevant Control code

```
public void LoadData() {
    SourceRecord[] original = new SourceRecord[] { 
        new SourceRecord("1"), new SourceRecord("3"), new SourceRecord("9") };
    gridControl1.DataSource = original;
    GridColumn col = gridView1.Columns.AddVisible("SomeColumn");
    col.FieldName = "SomeName";
    //gridControl1.ForceInitialize();
}
```

Record info

```
public class SourceRecord {
    public string SomeName = "";
    public SourceRecord(string Name) {
        this.SomeName = Name;
    }
}
```

I end up with some column just called "Column" which displays 3 rows reading `ClassLibrary1.SourceRecord`.  Then my custom column "Some Name" has no data.  According to the devexpress [walkthrough](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2387) I only need to populate the DataSource with a class that implements `IList`, which I did with an Array.

How can I display just my custom column and give it the data?

Comment: SomeName is a public _field_. Are you sure fields are supported? Try with a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grid control will bind columns to properties only. Try this:

```
public class SourceRecord
{
    public string SomeName { get; set; }
    public SourceRecord(string Name)
    {
        SomeName = Name;
    }
}

public void LoadData()
{
    SourceRecord[] original = new SourceRecord[] { new SourceRecord("1"), new SourceRecord("3"), new SourceRecord("9") };
    GridColumn col = gridView1.Columns.AddVisible("SomeColumn");
    col.FieldName = "SomeName";
    gridControl1.DataSource = original;
}
```